# Using redis with node.js (express)

Tags: node.js, redis, express

I am learning node.js (and express framework) & here is a basic newbie question about redis & node.js. How to pass redis data to templates? What should I correct in my script, so I could display the value of *teststring* in a template?

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    test: redisclient.get("teststring"),
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since node.js modules (including the one for redis) tends to be non-blocking and asynchronous, they are returning results in callbacks. Try it this way (I also recommend to read [this article](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/26/asynchronous-code-design-with-node-js/) regarding asynchronous code and callbacks):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  redisclient.get("teststring", function(error, response) {
    if(response) {
      res.render('index', {
        test: response,
      });
    } else {
      res.render('index', {
        test: error,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you check for error? Could there not be a response and an error?

Comment: @Chance - if there is an error, response should be undefined, therefore else clausule would be executed.